# Unusual Kinds and Data Constructors

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, dependent-type, data-kinds, type-kinds

I don't know how I didn't notice this, but data constructors and function definitions alike can't use types with kinds other than `*` and it's variants `* -> *` etc., due to `(->)`'s kind signature, even under `-XPolyKinds`.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data Nat = S Nat | Z

data Foo where
  Foo :: 'Z -> Foo -- Fails

foo :: 'Z -> Int -- Fails
foo _ = 1
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
<interactive>:8:12:
    Expected a type, but ‘Z’ has kind ‘Nat’
    In the type signature for ‘foo’: foo :: 'Z -> Int
```

Why shouldn't we allow pattern matching with non-traditional kinds?

Comment: All of these types are uninhabited. So one question is why you'd want to pattern match, and on what exactly?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the goal & capacities of the `singletons` library.

Comment: You can have types indexed by other types. The typical example is "Vec": `data Vec n a where Nil :: Vec Z a; Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a`. In a dependently typed language, you could write `pure : (n : Nat) -> a -> Vec n a`, but this is impossible in haskell, so `singletons` will automatically generate a type like `data SNat (n :: Nat) where SZ :: SNat Z; SS :: SNat n -> SNat (S n)`, so you can "fake" dependent types and write `pure :: SNat n -> a -> Vec n a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no<sup>1</sup> such thing as "types with kinds other than `*`". Kind `*` is *the* kind for types, much like `Int` is *the* type for machine-sized numbers; other kinds  may contain stuff that resembles types or can be converted to types or is used to index types or whatever – but is not *types as such*, merely "type level entities".

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>As usually, I disregard unbox-kinds here.</sub>

Comment: Note that while it's fine that you seem to accept only things of kind `*` as "types", there are many people who would call everything that has a kind a "type" (rather than a "type-level entity").