# Creating Haskell datatype accepting type of non-* kind in one of its constructors

Tags: haskell, type-kinds, haskell-ivory

Hello. I am playing with Ivory library which relies heavily on modern features of Haskell. Among others, it defines the typeclasses `IvoryType` accepting all types and `IvoryArea` accepting types of special kind `Area`. The definitions look like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

-- | Proxy datatype with a phantom arbitrary-kinded type
-- and a single constructor 
data Proxy (a :: k) = Proxy

-- | The kind of memory-area types.
data Area k
  = Struct Symbol
  | Array Nat (Area k)
  | CArray (Area k)
  | Stored k
    -- ^ This is lifting for a *-kinded type

class IvoryType t where
  ivoryType :: Proxy t -> I.Type {- arguments are not important -}

-- | Guard the inhabitants of the Area type, as not all *s are Ivory *s.
class IvoryArea (a :: Area *) where
  ivoryArea :: Proxy a -> I.Type {- arguments are not important -}
```

OK. Now let's try to express the fact that we are going to store values with `ivoryType` function defined. Obviously, they *are* the memebers of `IvoryType` class, so the answer is

```hs
data TypeStorage = TypeStorage (forall t . IvoryType t => t)
```

So far so good. Now we want to store values which have `ivoryArea` function defined. Let's use the `IvoryArea` class as a filter condition, like in the prevoius case:

```hs
data AreaStorage = AreaStorage (forall t . IvoryArea t => t)
```

Surprisingly, the compiler (ghc version 7.8.4) outputs an error

```hs
src/IvoryLL/Types.hs:59:45:
    Expected a type, but ‘t’ has kind ‘Area *’
    In the type ‘forall t. IvoryArea t => t’
    In the definition of data constructor ‘AreaBase’
    In the data declaration for ‘Area
```

Could you please explain, how to express the ownership of `ivoryArea` function in Haskell properly ?

**Edit**
Some links to the original declarations:

- https://github.com/GaloisInc/ivory/blob/master/ivory/src/Ivory/Language/Type.hs
- https://github.com/GaloisInc/ivory/blob/master/ivory/src/Ivory/Language/Area.hs

Comment: I've also tried rewriting AreaStorage as GADT with the same result

Comment: I can't reproduce your result: `f :: forall t . (IvoryArea t) => t
` get rejected by GHC for the same reason on my machine. Would you consider posting the implementation of it?

Comment: Most likely your `f` actually has a type like `forall t. (IvoryArea t) => Proxy t -> ...`.

Comment: So... you write that you "want to store instances of IvoryArea". consider what an instance would be. In particular `IvoryArea :: Area * -> GHC.Prim.Constraint`. But what is a value level inhabitant of `Area *` ? Types that are of kinds created by `DataKinds` don't have inhabitants...

Comment: Looks like you are right. f :: forall t . (IvoryArea t) => t  is rejected actually. I'll fix the question.

Comment: By "storing the instances" I mean I want to store datatypes which are instances of IvoryArea

Comment: So... what datatype could possibly be an instance of IvoryArea? Remember, values are inhabitants of kind `*` not kind `Area *`...

Comment: Lets see how they do it. [Struct.hs](https://github.com/GaloisInc/ivory/blob/master/ivory/src/Ivory/Language/Struct.hs)  contains the definition of type which are IvoryArea. Another example is [CArray.hs](https://github.com/GaloisInc/ivory/blob/master/ivory/src/Ivory/Language/CArray.hs) . They indeed do it in a tricky way: a) derive helper `instance (IvoryStruct sym, ASymbol sym) => IvoryArea ('Struct sym)`  b) derive helper class  `IvoryStruct` and only _then_ c) gain access to `ivoryArea` function in `(~>)` definition. Looks like I don't understand completely how do kinds work.

Comment: "I mean I want to store datatypes which are instances of IvoryArea" - You can only "store" values. There seems to be some critical misunderstanding about what a "value" is. There are no values of type `'Stored Int`, for example. Not even `undefined`, whose type is `forall (a :: *) . a`. Strictly speaking, values are not inhabitants of kind `*` - types of kind `*` are inhabitants of kind `*`. Values are inhabitants of types of kind `*`. You probably want to define a type indexed on Area (whose kind will be `Area * -> *`, perhaps, or maybe even `Area k -> *`).

Comment: I thought that `class IvoryArea (a :: Area *)` differs from `class IvoryType a` in that we accept not every type (*) but only a type of specific kind (Area *). But still we are speaking about _types_ which can have values in both cases.. Looks like it was the source of my mistake.

Comment: Actually I want to express a type-level constraint which would filter for me all types for which `ivoryArea`  function is defined. The presence of typeclass `IvoryArea` tells me that in runtime there will be some types which have `ivoryArea` function associated with them. I'd like to separate them from any others. The question is how to express it in Haskell

Comment: *Only* the kind `*` has values. No other kind has values (ignoring primitive stuff). `Area *` is not a "subkind" of `*` or anything of the sort - they are distinct kinds. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924699/unusual-kinds-and-data-constructors?rq=1) question.

Comment: "I want to express a type-level constraint which would filter for me all types for which ivoryArea function is defined." Unfortunately this is impossible, but for a completely different reason. You cannot, in any fashion, retrieve "all the instances of a class". Classes are open, so anyone can one day come along and add a new instance.

Comment: "..tells me that in runtime there will be some types which have ivoryArea function associated with them.. "  s/types/values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we've established in the comments that you can't do what you want directly, which is create a special "subkind" of all types, we *can* use a bit more legwork to get what you want.

We just use a (closed) type family to interpret your `Area *` kind into something of kind `*` and then GADT, indexed by `Area *`, to hold such values. We can then wrap the whole shebang up in an existential to store arbitrary values of such a kind, if so desired.

Consider this cut down example:

```
data Area k
  = Stored k
  | List (Area k)

type family InterpIvoryArea a :: * where
    InterpIvoryArea (Stored k) = k
    InterpIvoryArea (List a) = [InterpIvoryArea a]

data AreaStorage a where
    AreaStorage :: InterpIvoryArea a -> AreaStorage a

data AreaStorageExistential where
    AreaStorageExistential :: AreaStorage a -> AreaStorageExistential

testValue :: AreaStorageExistential
testValue = AreaStorageExistential (AreaStorage [1,2,3] :: AreaStorage (List (Stored Int)))
```